# Not getting the radio values and score of quiz script

Tags: php, html, sql

I am making a multiple choice quiz using php and sql. When I play the quiz and submit the answer it not show the score.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "ashu","ashua");
$db=mysql_select_db("quiz",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id");

if (empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "<form method=post action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">";
    echo "<table border=0>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $question = $row["question"];
        $opt1 = $row["opt1"];
        $opt2 = $row["opt2"];
        $opt3 = $row["opt3"];
        $answer = $row["answer"];

        echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>$opt1 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt1\"></td><td>$opt2 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt2\"></td><td>$opt3 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt3\"></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
elseif (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $score = 0;
    $total = mysql_num_rows($display);

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
        $answer = $result["answer"];
        $q = $result["q"];

        if ($q == $answer)  {
            $score++; 
        }

    }

    echo "<p align=center><b>You scored $score out of $total</b></p>";
    echo "<p>";

    if ($score == $total) {
        echo "Congratulations! You got every question right!";
    } elseif ($score/$total < 0.34) {
        echo "Oh dear. Not the best score, but don't worry, it's only a quiz.";
    } elseif ($score/$total > 0.67) {
        echo "Well done! You certainly know your stuff.";
    } else {
        echo "Not bad - but there were a few that caught you out!";
    }

    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>Here are the answers:";

    echo "<table border=0>";
    $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {

        $question = $row["question"];
        $answer = $row["answer"];
        $q = $row["q"];

        echo "<tr><td><br>$question</td></tr>";

        if ($q == $answer)  {
            echo "<tr><td>&raquo;you answered ${$q}, which is correct</td></tr>";
        } elseif ($q == "") {
            echo "<tr><td>&raquo;you didn't select an answer. The answer is $answer</td></tr>";
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td>&raquo;you answered ${$q}. The answer is $answer</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table></p>";
}

?>
```

when i submit or finish the quiz i get the result as

> You scored 0 out of 2
>
> Oh dear. Not the best score, but don't worry, it's only a quiz.
>
> Here are the answers:
>   Q1:Gaurav 
>   »you didn't select an answer. The answer is 1
>
> Q2:ashuas 
>   »you didn't select an answer. The answer is 12

it shows only correct answer not showing the the correct score and in amswer it alwas shows you didnt select and answer.

Comment: Instead of pasting all the code, Can you say in which part you face the issue ?

Comment: Improving formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You write `elseif  (!empty($_POST['submit']))`, but never access `$_POST` in the block that follows. Shouldn't you at least use `$POST` to check whether a posted answer is correct?

Instead, you are checking whether a posted answer is correct using

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
    $answer = $result["answer"];
    $q = $result["q"];

    if ($q == $answer) {
        $score++; 
    }
}
```

i.e. by looking at the database only.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your Answer** Just Replace with your code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "ashu","ashua");
$db=mysql_select_db("quiz",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id");

if (empty($_POST['submit'])) {


echo "<form method=post action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">";
echo "<table border=0>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {

$id = $row["id"];
$question = $row["question"];
$opt1 = $row["opt1"];
$opt2 = $row["opt2"];
$opt3 = $row["opt3"];
$answer = $row["answer"];

echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>$opt1 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt1\"></td><td>$opt2      <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt2\"></td><td>$opt3 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt3\"></td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

}

elseif  (!empty($_POST['submit'])) 

{



$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id");

$score = 0;
$total = mysql_num_rows($display);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($display)) 


    {
            $id = $result["id"];
            $q = $_POST["q$id"];


        $answer = $result["answer"];



    if ($q == $answer) 
    {
    $score++; 
    }

}

echo "<p align=center><b>You scored $score out of $total</b></p>";
echo "<p>";

if   ($score == $total) {
echo "Congratulations! You got every question right!";
}
elseif ($score/$total < 0.34) {
echo "Oh dear. Not the best score, but don't worry, it's only a quiz.";
}
elseif ($score/$total > 0.67) {
echo "Well done! You certainly know your stuff.";
}
else {
echo "Not bad - but there were a few that caught you out!";
}

echo "</p>";

echo "<p>Here are the answers:";

echo "<table border=0>";
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {

$question = $row["question"];
$answer = $row["answer"];
$q = $row["q"];

echo "<tr><td><br>$question</td></tr>";

if ($q == $answer) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>&raquo;you answered ${$q}, which is correct</td></tr>";
    }
elseif ($q == "") {
echo "<tr><td>&raquo;you didn't select an answer. The answer is $answer</td>     </tr>";
}
else {
echo "<tr><td>&raquo;you answered ${$q}. The answer is $answer</td></tr>";
}

}
echo "</table></p>";



}

?>
```

Comment: This you have to call  $q = $_POST["q$id"];